# Hyperledger Composer Playground Query

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Can we query using the Hyperledger Composer Playground or can we only query using the REST API? I read the tutorial, but it only shows how to query using the REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Pronoy says, you can use REST APIs. Alternative is to set up a transaction, that calls a defined query (in queries,qry) - purely for testing and logging messages etc. Eg.

```
return query('selectPerson', {firstName: 'joe'} )
    .then(function (results) {

       for (var n = 0; n < results.length; n++) {
               var person = results[n];
               console.log('person is ' + (n+1) + ', object is ' +  person);
               console.log('person identifier is ' + person.getIdentifier());

         return personRegistry.get(person.getIdentifier())
         .then(function (personRecord) {
            console.log('object is ' + personRecord); // all good
           console.log('identifier is ' + person.getIdentifier() );
         })



       } // for

  }) //function
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do HTTP requests with the Playground, but you can test all the transactions and assets in your network. With the REST API, you can do HTTP requests plus CRUD all the transactions and assets in your network.